# trouble retrieving data from firebase in flutter dart application. cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Error im receiving :
StateError (Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist)

```html
Future getUserInterests(userId) async {
    User currentUser = User();

    await _firestore.collection('users').doc(userId).get().then((user) {
      currentUser.photo = user.get('name');
      currentUser.photo = user.get('photoUrl');
      currentUser.gender = user.get('gender');
      currentUser.subject = user.get('subject');
      
    });
    return currentUser;
  }
```

the name field does exist in my firebase collection thing

here is an image of my database, ignore how gender says 10th lol

[image: database]

Comment: add a screenshot of ur database to the question

Comment: done! do you know why I am getting this error?

Comment: Could you do some debugging and see which field is causing the error. Just add a print statement after every user.get(). Then we'll be able to see what is causing the error exactly

Answer (score 4):

You need to do the following:

```
currentUser.name = user.data()['name'];
currentUser.photo = user.data()['photoUrl'];
currentUser.gender = user.data()['gender'];
currentUser.subject = user.data()['subject'];
```

Comment: Peter Hadad it is a mistake but it is not what is causing the error

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore/lib/src/document_snapshot.dart#L38 `user` is of type `DocumentSnapshot` and if you check the code you have to use `data()` to get the fields from a document

Comment: Oh I had not noticed that change sorry

Comment: I had that same code before but it gave me the same error so I changed it to get

Comment: I had the same error, and adding `.data()` after my document instance solved it! Thanks!